# When should I use callback function in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I used to coding C/C++ and I just start to learn TS. One thing particularly confuse me is that TS is not always run at top-down. Like in below example, it will print "2 1".

```
    function first(){
      // Simulate a code delay
      setTimeout( function(){
        console.log(1);
      }, 500 );
    }
    function second(){
      console.log(2);
    }
    first();
    second();
```

But how can I know if one function can be executed *fast enough* so the program can run at top-down pattern? And I can image if I keep using recursive call back to *simulate* top-down pattern in my whole program, it will be a total chaos.

Comment: If you take C++ and spawn a thread in `first` that sleeps for 500ms, then `std::cout`s,  would it surprise you its output comes later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguably in 2019 you should never use a callback. Instead you should use a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

this allows the developer to choose either using a callback OR using more modern async/await

Example:

```js
function first() {
  // Simulate a code delay
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(1);
      resolve();
    }, 500);
  });
}

function second() {
  console.log(2);
}

(async() => {
  await first();
  second();
})();
```

or

```js
function first() {
  // Simulate a code delay
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(1);
      resolve();
    }, 500);
  });
}

function second() {
  console.log(2);
}

first().then(second);
```

Also we can just wrap setTimeout itself

```js
function wait(ms = 0) {
 return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function first() {
  await wait(500);
  console.log(1);
}

function second() {
  console.log(2);
}

(async() => {
  await first();
  second();
})();
```

One more example to show that using promises makes async/await possible which makes your code easy to follow avoiding the nesting hell you mentioned

```js
function wait(ms = 0) {
 return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function main() {
  await wait(1000);
  console.log('Each')
  await wait(1000);
  console.log('Of')
  await wait(1000);
  console.log('These');
  await wait(1000);
  console.log('Messages');
  await wait(1000);
  console.log('appears');
  const words = ['one', 'second', 'after', 'the', 'previous']
  for (const word of words) {
    await wait(1000);
    console.log(word);
  }
}
main();
```

Further if you're new to JavaScript/TypeScript coming from C/C++ you should learn about [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) as unlike C/C++ there is never any reason to provide a *userdata* argument for callbacks.

Also as @Sudip Sarker mentioned read up on the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), JavaScript is single threaded and runs on an "event loop". The parts that run in parallel are in the browser itself and the APIs JavaScript calls (loading an image, calling fetch, waiting for a timeout, etc...). JavaScript itself just runs one "event" at a time and then exits waiting for the next event.

Comment: Hi @gman, thanks for your reply! I read the documents you recommand. Just wanna confirm my understanding is right, the asycn is actually not depends on/triger by how fast a function can run, but by "configuration"(to put into queue or not)? So as described on my question, a complicated calculation is not actually automatically be set to run parallelized?

Comment: Correct, a complicated calculation will not run in parallel. The only way to run things in parallel in JavaScript is to use a [Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker).

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn basic JavaScript to understand how this works. There's a thing called the "Event Loop" which is causing this behavior. In short, the callback you provide to the `setTimeout` function goes to the callback queue and enters the callback stack (processes are executed from the callback stack). Then all the process in the stack are executed. You can do an interesting thing: Set the time to 0 and see what happens.

JavaScript isn't an asynchronous language. It's this event loop concept which makes JavaScript work asynchronously, but, behind the scenes, everything is working synchronously like in C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is transpiled to Javascript at the compilation time. So at run-time there is no Typescript around, only Javascript.

Javascript engine implements two queues: event queue and microtask queue. The latter has higher priority and is used by Promises.

Consider this code and its printout:

```js
console.log('start');
setTimeout(function() {                               // queue to event queue                  
  console.log('timeout');
}, 0);
Promise.resolve().then(function() {                  // queue to microtask queue     
  console.log('promise1');
}).then(function() { console.log('promise2'); });    // queue to microtask queue
console.log('end');



start
end             // current call stack empty after printing so look at the queues
promise1        // dequeue and process a task from microtask queue
promise2        // keep doing the above ignoring the main event queue
timeout         // microtask queue empty so do dequeue and process an event from event queue
```